# Can action buttons be added to dashboard table on activeadmin?

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I have this code that creates a table on the activeadmin Dashboard:

```
columns do 
  column do
    panel "New Mentor's requests" do
      table_for User.where(mentor_request: true) do |t|
        t.column("Id") { |user| user.id }
        t.column("Name") { |user| user.account.full_name }
        t.column("Email") { |user| user.account.email }
        t.column("Organization") { |user| user.organization.name }

      end

    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to add "actions" like on the rest of the resources? I mean like "new, edit, delete", but a custom one.

I tried putting the "actions" tag, but I get an undefined method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`table_for` is used to render a collection of objects which may not necessarily be ActiveRecord objects, so the action methods aren't available like they are in an `index` action. However, you should be able to render your own actions with something like this:

```
column("View User") { |user| link_to "View", user_path(user) }
```

**EDIT** For multiple links you can wrap the `link_to`s use Arbre's span tag:

```
column("View User") do |user|
  span link_to "View", "/mypath"
  span link_to "Edit", "/mypath"
  span link_to "Delete", "/mypath"
end
```

I'm using ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2 w/ arbre 1.0.2, I haven't tried it on earlier versions.

Comment: That's perfect. Would it be possible to add two action buttons on the same column?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  actions :all
  index do
    column :name
    actions defaults: true do |foo|
      link_to "Custom ACTION", custom_action_path(foo.id)
    end
  end
end
```

It worked for me to have **more options** than the already defined ones: *View*, *Edit*, *Delete*

Source: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/53